# Selectpicker cancel change value event

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Consider the following event:

```
$(`#selectpicker).on('change', function(){
if(condition) {} else 
{
  //canceel event change
}
});
```

How to cancel the change event based on specific condition therefore maintaining the same select picker value.

Comment: You could `disable` the options you do not wish to be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for? Set a variable for the current value and if an undesired value is selected we set the value of the select field back to the recent value.

```
<select id="selectpicker">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

let currentValue = $('#selectpicker').val();
$('#selectpicker').on('change', function(){
  let newValue = $(this).val();
  
  if(newValue == 3){
    console.log("3 is not allowed");
    $(this).val(currentValue);
    return;
  }
  currentValue = $('#selectpicker').val();
})
```

You could also disable certain options with "disabled" keyword, but keep in mind that this can be easily bypassed from developer tools.

```
<option disabled value="3">3</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can stop the execution of the callback with `return false`, the value will already have changed when this event is triggered. If you want to return to the previous value, you have to store it somehow, either in a variable or in a `data` property on the element. Then you can set the value back in your condition, or update the variable when your cancel-condition is not met.